# Why are some libraries in iOS provided by C-based API?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-graphics

Why are some libraries in iOS provided C based API? For example, Core Graphics library is provided by C based API. But, I can't understand the reason why Apple did it.

Moreover, `[[UIColor red] setStroke]` which is the kind of code in drawRect: also makes me confused! If Apple decided to use C based API, why do they use object oriented style code doing graphic things?

And `CGContextAddLineToPoint()`, for example, takes argument `CGContextRef c`. I think it's completely suitable to use object oriented things.

```
// current
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextMoveToPoint(context, 0, 0);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 10, 10);

// looks better
CGContext *context = [UIGraphics getCurrentContext]
[context moveToPoint: CGMakePoint(0, 0)] // or [context moveToPointX: 0 y: 0]
[context addLineToPoint: CGMakePoint(10, 10)]  // or [context addLineToPointX: 10 y: 10]
```

So, why does Apple use C based API on some libraries?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Performance

1. as there's less memory overhead in C compared to an Objective-C object
2. speedup as there's no need to go through the Objective-C runtime

Comment: Also this allows the caller to be in C, which allows for the highest performance when required by the caller. As a note, however, CoreFoundation objects are about the same size as ObjC objects, so it's often not a memory overhead issue.

Comment: However, how about Java? In the Java, we usually draw some elements using object oriented way. Like this `graphics.drawLine(0, 0, 10, 10);`

Comment: @JonghwanHyeon - in Java (and C++ and C# too for that matter) the compiler knows exactly what function is going to be called and can generate a direct call to it. In the worst case scenario, it's a virtual function and there is an additional memory dereference, but that's nothing compared to having to search a table for the appropriate function. Objective-C is different. It's actually a very dynamic language. You can add methods to any object at run-time. The compiler has no choice but to generate the call to do the lookup since it can't predict what function is going to eventually be called.

Comment: Further to what @Ferruccio said, a brief writeup on this late (or dynamic) binding is at http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/DynamicBinding.html

Answer (score 6):

One possible reason is performance.

When you send a message to an object, the compiler translates it to a call to a C function named `objc_msgSend()` which takes as parameters the object you're sending the message to, the message and any parameters to the message. It then does a look up to figure out where the actual function corresponding to that message is located and passes control to it.

I'm sure Apple has optimized the hell out of `objc_msgSend` since it's called so often, but it's still going to be a lot slower than a simple function call.

Answer (score 4):

One reason for the abstraction can be found in Apple's history.  When Cocoa made its Mac debut (as the Yellow Box in the Rhapsody OS), many large developers were unwilling to port their user interfaces to it.  As a result, the existing Mac Toolbox was cleaned up and released alongside Cocoa as "Carbon" when Mac OS X 10.0 shipped.

Carbon and Cocoa had a lot of feature overlap, so the creation of shared, C-based libraries made a lot of sense.  While Carbon has fallen in popularity, iOS has emerged, and the C libraries continue to be useful for abstraction between Apple's operating systems— between AppKit and UIKit.

---

**N.B.:** As a rule of thumb, you should try to use the highest-level API that meets your needs.  For example, if `UIBezierPath` and `UIColor` will give you what you want, then you can (and probably should) stay in the Objective-C garden for readability, ease-of-debugging, and futureproofing.  However, as functionality and performance requirements demand, you can always fall back to CoreGraphics.  In the same vein, if you need to handle threaded, concurrent tasks within your app, `NSOperation` subclasses are a clean and consistent way to go, but if your needs are unique, you can always fall back to GCD `dispatch_()` methods.

Answer (score 2):

For one thing, `C` is a lower-level language with less overhead. When you introduce objects, you introduce a little overhead in exchange for a program structure that is easier to follow in most circumstances.

Also, because of the fact that both iOS and OS X are based on a Unix kernel, any low-level OS integration that is provided in an Apple API is either written in a more commonly used cross-platform language like `C` or it is written as a wrapper for those very same `C` functions. At some point, it is not worth Apple's time to provide `Objective-C` wrappers for everything.